# Patching Angular Reactive Forms with FormArray of FormGroups

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building a form similar to this:

```
private _buildForm(): FormGroup {
const _form = new FormGroup({
  title: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  jobs: new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      _id: new FormControl(''),
      status: new FormControl('')
      });
    ])
  });
}
```

When I want to patch the form using the patchValue() method (for example, when the data comes back from the server), the jobs array is only patched for one element.  In other words, if the jobs array contains more than one job, only the first job FormGroup is patched.  I thought Angular would be smart enough to dynamically add as many FormGroups as required to match.  How else can the job FormGroups be patched?

Comment: You can dynamically add as many `FormGroup` instances to the `FormArray` as you like, but in the above code there is only one. You need to add the logic to add controls to a `FormArray`.

Comment: please check updated code in the answer.

Comment: As Will Alexander say, you can use pathValue, the problem is that you need that the formArray has the same length than the data **before** make the pathValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't patch formArray this way. what you can do pass the formArray value as parameter and insert it in the form one by one.

```
setUpForm(job: Job) {
  return new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl(job.title), 
    statuses: new FormArray(job.statuses.map((status) => this.createStatus(status))) 
  });
}
createStatus(statuses: any) {
  return new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(statuses.id || ''),
    status: new FormControl(statuses.status || ''),
  })
}
```

Live Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-patch)